# Why are Virtual Terminal Blank using NVIDIA propietary drivers?

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, vaio, virtual-terminal

When using nouveau the fps are low compared to nvidia closed driver. But when booting, nvidia drivers show the ubuntu splash screen in a 900x800 resolution like nvidia its not loaded yet. When nouveau it splash in a decent resolution.

The problem I'm having since karmic koala is I cant switch to virtual terminals with nvidia closed drivers. By the way, is the same PC: VAIO VPCCW19FX with NVIDIA G210M, now with precise amd64.

To make easy to read the configs, I pastedbin'ed each file in differents pastes.

/etc/X11/xorg.conf >> http://pastebin.com/Ly7n5d2T

/etc/default/grub >> http://pastebin.com/VPBYkRVS

lsmod  >> http://pastebin.com/a7q3z9ZL

lspci  >> http://pastebin.com/bd4vPCPf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when booting, nvidia drivers show the ubuntu splash screen in a 900x800 resolution like nvidia its not loaded yet. When nouveau it splash in a decent resolution.

This is because the nvidia proprietary drivers do not support Kernel Modesetting (KMS).  This is normal when you are using the nvidia proprietary drivers - with these drivers you should not normally expect your screen to switch to full resolution prior to boot, like you do with other open source drivers.

It's possible that a framebuffer mode is being entered and there is a problem with that somehow.

I don't know a fix but I can suggest troubleshooting steps that may help you get what you want.

In my /etc/default/grub, I have removed "splash" from the kernel command line, and uncommented the `GRUB_TERMINAL=console` line in order to give up totally on graphical boot.

But you could also try, instead, just adding "vga=normal" to your kernel command line (next to "quiet splash").  This should try and prevent a framebuffer mode loading.

Comment: I also need to remove the $vthandoff but I have to do it manually at grub screen because I cant see this line in /etc/default/grub. How can I remove $vthandoff for every boot?

We have another problem houston my vt4 turns into 4 since the screen is splitted into 4 not equally screens. Just like damage tv. I backup my conf so I can get back any time.

Comment: This is the correct answer. It work but I didnt like what I've found. Nvidia driver just split my screen into 4 on virtual terminals. This is nothing new. We all know NVIDIA.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by neon_overload, adding "vga=normal" to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT line in /etc/default/grub totally fixed the vterm problem for me, while keeping the same boot behaviour (i.e. the grub menu and splash screen are unchanged)!

EDIT: Sadly, after changing the screen resolution with NVIDIA's configuration tool, switching to virtual terminals again gives me no output. Nonetheless, this is still a partial fix.

Comment: With recent drivers, using nomodeset instead of vga=normal appears to work just fine even through resolution changes.