# Virtual terminal (CTRL+ALT+(Fx) doesn't work

Tags: command-line, virtual-terminal

I'm trying to get to any virtual terminal by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> (for example) but the only thing I get is a black screen with the underscore blinking in the upper-left corner. The only thing I can do at this point is manually reboot the computer. Wasn't there supposed to be a terminal? What's happening?

Comment: If you're using nvidia proprietary drivers, then this might help: http://askubuntu.com/q/150610/83046

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's all your supposed to see. Try typing in your user name and see what happens. You may have to log in even though your computer isn't telling you that for some reason.

If you want your regular display back, simply press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>